# How to solve the error 'std::out_of_range' what(): _M_range_check , vector will accept values until told to break

Tags: c++, vector

Hi i'm trying to create what would be a pretty simple vector programme to take in integers, and then when prompted, display the largest, in c++. However I'm new to this and have inevitably made an arse of it. As stated above it throws the error  'std::out_of_range' what():  _M_range_check , and does accept values until prompted to break. But I can't figure out why , even after browsing this forum for quite a while. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int inputVector (vector<int>);   //prototype functions
void sortVector    (int,vector<int>&files);
void displayVector (vector<int>&files);

int main()
{
    int vectorsize=(0);

    vector <int>files;

    files.reserve(10);

    vectorsize=inputVector (files);

    sortVector (vectorsize, files);

    displayVector (files);

    return 0;

}

void displayVector(vector<int>& files)
{

    cout << " The largest file size is " << files.at(0);

}

int  inputVector(vector<int>files)
{
    int file=0;
    int vectorsize;

    cout << "Enter file sizes  in Megabytes, file size has to be 1 or greater,                                                hit 0 to display max value " << endl;

    do
    {
        cin >> file;

        if (file==0)
        {
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            files.push_back(file) ; //sends value to the vector

            cout << files.size() << endl;
        }
    }
    while (file>0);

    vectorsize=files.size();
    return vectorsize;

}

void sortVector(int vectorsize,vector<int>&files)
{
    int maximum;

    for( int j=0;j<vectorsize;j++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<(vectorsize-1);i++)
        {
            if(files.at(i)< files.at(i+1))
            {
                maximum=files.at(i);
                files.at(i)=files.at(i+1);
                files.at(i+1)=maximum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you at least *look* at the question preview?

Comment: yes , hence the mention of me browsing the forum.

Comment: No, I meant the horrible formatting which was in your question before gareththegeek put it into at least some shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `vectorsize` was wrong and hence your call

```
files.at(i);  // in sortvector()
```

caused an out-of-range error. The actual vector size was `0`, but your program assumed something else. This was caused by passing the `vector` by value to the function `vectorinput()`: on return of that function, the original vector was not altered and the returned `vectorsize` meaningless.

Do to what you've tried to do one would rather

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void inputVector (vector<int>&);

int main()
{
  vector<int> files;
  inputVector(files);
  // std::sort(files.begin(),files.end(),std::greater<int>()); // not needed
  std::cout << " The largest file size is "
            << std::max_element(files.begin(),files.end()) << std::endl;
}

void inputVector(vector<int>&files)
{
  std::cout << "Enter file sizes in Megabytes, file size has to be 1 or "
               "greater, enter 0 to display max value " << std::endl;
  files.reserve(10); // not really needed
  while(true) {
    int file;
    std::cin >> file;
    if (file>0) {
      files.push_back(file);
      // std::cout << files.size() << std::endl; // for debugging
    } else
      break;
  }
}
```

but, of course, there is no need to store the file sizes in a vector if you only want to find the maximum.

Comment: thanks I've changed it now to pass by reference ,as suggested by you and another commentor.

Comment: I knew the file reserve wasnt really needed, but thought , why not. Thanks a lot for the effort in answering this , I appreaciate it.

Comment: it doesnt show due to low reputation, or at least what it tells me.

Answer (score 1):

`inputVector` takes the vector by value so it's modifying a copy. Pass it by reference instead. Also you don't need to pass around the vector size since you can just call `size()`.

Comment: How would I call size?

Comment: @goon1345 `files.size()`

Comment: cheers, gives me no matching function call error now , but i'll see if i can fix that myself.